# Цена, привязанная к атрибуту в woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как можно для одного вариативного товара в woocommerce к атрибуту привязать цену?
т.е. чтобы не прописывать цену для каждой характеристики отдельно в вариациях, а чтобы цена подтягивалась, в зависимости от выбранной характеристики в админке, т.е. от выбранного атрибута.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

атрибуты могут иметь такую структуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Необходимо сделать так чтобы сумма стоимости выбранных характеристик просчитывалась автоматически

Comment: Похоже, вот такое решение подойдёт: https://www.storeapps.org/product/bulk-variations-manager/ Бесплатные плагины мне неизвестны.

Comment: @KAGG Design, а с помощью сгруппированных товаров это реализовать можно?  
Есть ли пример, где можно посмотреть на реализацию данной возможности без плагина?

Comment: Мне о таких примерах неизвестно. Всё сделать можно, но кода для реализации задачи в вопросе должно быть достаточно много.

Comment: @KAGG Design, а подскажите, выше на скрине видно, что для одной вариации товара могут быть заданы такие параметры, верхняя и нижняя часть в миллиметрах. т.е. к примеру только для верхней части втулки нет смысла задавать цену, т.к. нужны параметры ещё нижней части.
Мне немного не понятна постановка задачи. Проясните пожалуйста, мало работал с вариациями, т.е. как это должно быть реализовано? хотя-бы на словах

Comment: Я думаю, постановка задачи сама по себе плохая, со стороны заказчика. Ему кажется, что все легко и просто, а это далеко не так. Если есть связанные атрибуты (верхняя и нижняя часть), то код ещё более усложняется.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такой плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/markup-by-attribute-for-woocommerce/ который позволяет указывать цену для атрибутов.